# Using rvest to get the number of confirmed cases of coronavirus

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to create a **scraper** to get updates on the number of cases of coronavirus and I am using the page below.

When I give the xpath to the number of confirmed cases it shows "0" and not the real number that apears on the page when I inspect it Google Chrome's Dev Tools. Does anyone knows what is wrong here?

```
library(rvest)

response = read_html('https://news.qq.com/zt2020/page/feiyan.htm', encoding = 'GBK')

response %>%
  html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="charts"]/div[3]/div[1]')

{html_node}
<div class="icbar confirm">
[1] <div class="number">0</div>
[2] <div class="text">全国确诊</div>
```

Comment: The data is probably being dynamically loaded using Javascript. When I use dev tools to see which files are being download (the Network tab in Firefox's dev tools, not sure about Chrome), I see a JSON file with a name like `disease_h5` that seems to contain the numbers, you might be able to get that JSON data directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Marius you can get the data from JSON file which is loaded. I got the `url` from the developer tools, read the html as text and get the number which is followed by `"confirm"`.

```
url <- 'https://view.inews.qq.com/g2/getOnsInfo?name=disease_h5&callback=jQuery34108850961227842673_1580448523488&_=1580448523489'

library(rvest)
url %>% 
  read_html() %>%
  html_text() %>%
  stringr::str_match('confirm.*?(\\d+)') %>% .[,2] %>% as.integer()

#[1] 9731
```